# Issue calculating distances in google maps only in Panama

Tags: sql-server, google-maps, t-sql

I have encountered a problem that is driving me crazy.

A few years ago i developed a browser app that calculate the distance from one given point (latitude and longitude coords) to anothers given points.

Everything has worked fine until a few days ago when a client from Panama started working with us. The same SQL procedure that works for years is giving us wrong measurements.

This is the SQL formula:

```
(Acos(Sin((Ofd.Latitud * PI()) / 180) * Sin((@Longitud * PI()) / 180) + Cos((Ofd.Latitud * PI()) / 180) * Cos((@Longitud * PI()) / 180) * Cos((Ofd.Logitud * PI() / 180) - (@Latitud * PI()) / 180)) * 6371 * 1000) AS Distance
```

I tried to calculate the distance using the new method since SQL 2008

```
DECLARE @Latitude float = 8.9749377
DECLARE @Longitude float = -79.5060562
DECLARE @TLatitude float = 8.9868425
DECLARE @TLongitude float = -79.5012872
DECLARE @Source geography
DECLARE @Target geography

SET @Source = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(@Latitude as varchar(20)) + ' ' + CAST(@Longitude as varchar(20)) + ')',4326)
SET @Target = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(@TLatitude as varchar(20)) + ' ' + CAST(@TLongitude as varchar(20)) + ')',4326)

SELECT @source.STDistance(@Target)
```

The diference between the two methods is negligible, a few meters. The distance that returns the method is ~500m

So, the problem is that the real distance is almost 1500 meters, I've seen and measured the distance in google maps and 1.500 meters is the real distance. The funny side is that, this problem, only happens in Panama. With the clients in Spain we have no problem calculating the distance.

Have I found the Bermuda's triangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the Latitude and Longitude reversed.  WKT POINT coordinates are ordered X,Y (Longitude, Latitude).

```
DECLARE @Latitude float = 8.9749377
DECLARE @Longitude float = -79.5060562
DECLARE @TLatitude float = 8.9868425
DECLARE @TLongitude float = -79.5012872
DECLARE @Source geography
DECLARE @Target geography

SET @Source = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(@Longitude as varchar(20)) + ' ' + CAST(@Latitude as varchar(20)) + ')',4326)
SET @Target = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(@TLongitude as varchar(20)) + ' ' + CAST(@TLatitude as varchar(20)) + ')',4326)

SELECT @source.STDistance(@Target)
```